# Dynamic date selected and current month is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

This is [my problem link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-day-picker-examplesselected-jet2d)

I am passing dynamic date array and getting month based on the current date but it is not working.

This is [reference link](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/selected)

Comment: I don't see any state or props, how you component could be reative and update itself ? You can call `this.selectedDaysS` directly like that : `selectedDays={
          this.selectedDaysS(["2019-07-25"]);
        }`

Comment: You return `nothing` in `selectedDays` props of `DayPicker`

Comment: @TienDuong I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: `selectedDays={() => { this.selectedDaysS(["2019-07-25"]) }}`, as you can see, you don't return a value in here

Comment: @Hurobaki Then that metho will execute onload, but if I call `selectedDays={ this.selectedDaysS(["2019-07-25"]) }` like this then also nothing happens

Comment: @TienDuong yes right but , but if I call `selectedDays={ this.selectedDaysS(["2019-07-25"]) }` like this then also nothing happens

Comment: @TienDuong So, can you show me how can I achieve that?

Comment: @HarshPatel ShubhamVerma has helped you

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass an array instead of function call in `selectedDays` and you are passing date parameter wrong in `selectedDaysS` function :

```
selectedDaysS = daysArr => {
    let dataToSend = daysArr.map(a => {
      let m = a.split('-');
      return new Date(m[0], m[1], m[2]);
    });

    return dataToSend;
  };
```

and inside render :

```
return (
      <DayPicker
        initialMonth={this.currentMonth()}
        selectedDays={this.selectedDaysS(["2019-07-25"])}
      />
    );
```

Here is live link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-day-picker-examplesselected-nfbgz?fontsize=14